# Copy all SBT dependencies to local folder

Tags: scala, playframework, docker, sbt

I'm dockerizing my Play! Framework application and currently, my build is taking more than 15 minutes to complete. A large part of the process, it is actually downloading dependencies because my builder has no notion of caches yet. I thought, it would be a good idea to copy all the dependencies that my project needs, to a local folder so it doesn't have to download everything again and again. However, problem is, I don't know how to do that? I know SBT has a function that allows you to specify a local repo, but I'm unaware of a functionality that allows me to copy everything to a certain folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** (2015-07-13):

OK, so what you want is keeping all the dependencies in the folder you want, you can try this when you run sbt,

```
sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=/your/local/path/.ivy
```

Then it will keep all the dependencies files or any files downloaded for building your app in `/your/local/path/.ivy/cache`.

If you want to keep them in your project,

```
sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=/some/path/to/your-project/.ivy
```

Then the files will be stored in the `/some/path/to/your-project/.ivy/cache` folder.

By the way, docker doesn't support cache? Hmmm why don't you try some nice CI service like [Semaphore CI](https://semaphoreci.com/) and let it deploy your app to Docker? (I have NO personal or any other connection to Semaphore. It's just the service I use and I tried about five different CI tools and like that one the most).

**Updated** (2015-07-12): Oh, sorry your question is not about using local repo but copying everything to it.

This might not be exactly what you asked but can probably solve your issue.

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

Note: It's an experimental feature.

Details: [sbt doc - Cached-Resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html)

===============================================

You can specify the repository by

```
resolvers += name at location
```

Like

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

So for local maven repo, you can simply do

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Yet, in my case, when I did it, it tried to access `PROJECT_HOME/{user.home}/.m2/repository` which is incorrect.

What I wanted was `$HOME/.m2/repository` which is the location of the maven local repository. So I put the following line in `build.sbt` instead of `Resolver.mavenLocal`, and it seems to work.

```
resolvers += "mavenLocal" at s"${sys.props("user.home")}/.m2/repository"
```

Details: [sbt doc - Library-Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html)

Comment: I haven't seen any functionality that allows me to completely download all the dependencies. That's what I'm after. Still thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MartijnR Well I do this in build.sbt `resolvers += "mavenLocal" at s"${sys.props("user.home")}/.m2/repository"` and it doesn't seem to download the dependency libs again when it finds them at the `mavenLocal`.

Comment: Yeah, problem is. I'm using docker which means there is no cache preserved. And it would be stupid to copy over my whole maven cache because it contains a lot of unrelated stuff. :(

Comment: @MartijnR OK, got it. I've updated my answer and what you want is keeping the files in some folder inside your project folder or any other folder you want, that might be the answer. So please read the updated one. :)

Comment: that is actually the solution I'm using now. Was hoping there would be a better way. I now compile the project on my own computer and create a tar.gz file which contains the ivy cache and host it on S3. When my docker wants to build, it pulls from there and uses it for the build. A very sloppy solution but it's the best I could do. Git doesn't allow the huge ivy cache to be pushed so this was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try sbt pack plugin https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack
It has packCopyDependencies task. Maybe that is what you are looking for.